# SOLR index on pdate field included in search results

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am migrating from SOLR 4.10.2 to 8.1.1. For some reason, in the 8.1.1 core, a pdate index named IDX_ExpirationDate is appearing as a field in the search results documents.

I have several other indexes that are defined and (correctly) do not appear in the results. But the index I am having trouble with is the only one based on a pdate.

Here is a sample 8.1.1 response that demonstrates the issue:

```
"response":{"numFound":58871,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"11111",
        "ExpirationDate":"2018-01-26T00:00:00Z",
        "_version_":1641033044033798170,
        "IDX_ExpirationDate":["2018-01-26T00:00:00Z"]},
      {
        "id":"22222",
        "ExpirationDate":"2018-02-20T00:00:00Z",
        "_version_":1641032965380112384,
        "IDX_ExpirationDate":["2018-02-20T00:00:00Z"]},
```

ExpirationDate is supposed to be there, but IDX_ExpirationDate should not. I know that I can probably keep using date, but it is deprecated, and part of the reason for upgrading to 8.1.1 is to use the latest non-deprecated stuff ;-)

I have an index named IDX_ExpirationDate based on a field called ExpirationDate that was a date field in 4.10.2:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<field name="IDX_ExpirationDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="ExpirationDate" type = "date" indexed = "true" stored = "true" />
<copyField source="ExpirationDate" dest="IDX_ExpirationDate"/>
```

In the 8.1.1 core, I have this configured as a pdate:

```
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
<field name="IDX_ExpirationDate" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />    
<field name="ExpirationDate" type = "pdate" indexed = "true" stored = "true" />
<copyField source="ExpirationDate" dest="IDX_ExpirationDate"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

According to Shawn Heisey on the solruser mailing list, the pdate type defaults to docValues=true and useDocValuesAsStored="true", which makes it appear in results.

So I changed the IDX_ExpirationDate by adding useDocValuesAsStored="false", reloaded the index, and it no longer appears in the results:

```
<field name="IDX_ExpirationDate" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" useDocValuesAsStored="false"/>
```